# Is a question about the usage of browser plug-ins on-topic (NoScript)

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to configure my [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) Firefox plugin to allow everything coming from Stack Exchange (so, adzerk may serve me JavaScript code on Stack Overflow, but nowhere else).

Would such a question be on topic on Stack Overflow?

On the one hand, the configuration is [very programmy](https://noscript.net/abe/), on the other hand it is not a tool that is primary targeted at programmers.

If it's off-topic here and you might know a Stack Exchange site I can ask it, I'd be glad to know.

Comment: I'd go with http://superuser.com for this one.

Comment: Related (cross-site): *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)*. It contains input for JavaScript whitelisting (which is the central functionality of NoScript and the subject of this question) - near ***"The following sites should be accessible"***, cookies, etc. In fact, I think you already have the answer there.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks for the link, but this only cares about the functional requirements (as it should) but not about the advertisement stuff (adzerk).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the question is about something you're *programming*, it's not suitable for Stack Overflow.  In this case, since you're describing a browser plugin which enjoys a sizable user base, but isn't directly something you're coding, I'd say that [Super User](http://superuser.com) is the best fit.

You may want to double check that this isn't already asked; this isn't a terribly difficult thing to configure.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's about SO is fairly tangential, and it should be fairly obvious that a question about configuring a browser plugin to execute scripts from a given third-party domain only on, say, nytimes.com is *not* a programming question at all, but a general computer usage one. (Just because you probably want to use a monospace font to edit a config file does not make it on topic here. Consider any of the numerous human-readable *nix config files that are mostly or entirely off-topic to ask about here.) Super User is the place to go.

Theoretically, IT Security might work as well; in practice, I doubt it would fit as well there.

Comment: I didn't mean it to be on-topic because its about SO, but because the type of configuration is not a GUI but code.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs: I've written ABE rulesets, and they're about as much code as your average sudoers file.